# Renaming a column with value from another column plus sequence

Tags: oracle11g, sequence

I have a table TBL_CLASS with the structure

```
CLASS_NAME | CLASS_TYPE
Maths        PRI      
Math         SEC
English      PRI
English      PAR
Physics      PAR
Biology      BIO
```

What I want to do is to update the ClassCode column with the value Maths and a sequence starting from 0001 instead of 1 so that the table above will become

```
CLASS_NAME | CLASS_TYPE | CLASS_CODE
Maths        MATH        MATH0001 
Math         MATH        MATH0002
English      ENG         ENG0001
English      ENG         ENG0002
Physics      PHY         PHY0001
Biology      BIO         BIO0001
```

Is it possible to do this just in the database without filling the first column with MATH0001 or ENG0001 for each column or creating a temp column?

I could create a temp column with the sequence but I'd still have to fill in the first number into the column and then selecting the MAX

```
SELECT MAX(substr(TEMP_CODE, -4)) AS LAST4DIGIT FROM TBL_CLASS WHERE CLASS_TYPE= 'MATHS'
```

And then updating the column with the update statement

```
UPDATE TBL_CLASS SET CLASS_CODE = CLASS_TYPE||TEMP_COL
```

What I'd like to achieve is to update the ClassCode with a statement like

`UPDATE TBL_CLASS SET CLASS_CODE = CLASS_NAME|| <sequence>` without filling in the first value (0001) for each class and adding sequence into the temp column.

Appreciate any pointers on how I could approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL shows how you can manipulate with the column output. You can use this to update your table if that's what you want. If you need to add a new (eg. Math) row and need to find the indexnumber you can use eg. `REGEXP_SUBST` to extract only numbers and then remove the front zeros (and add 1).

```
SELECT class_name,
       SUBSTR (UPPER (class_name),
               1,
               CASE WHEN UPPER (class_name) LIKE 'MATH%' THEN 4 ELSE 3 END)
          class_type,
          SUBSTR (
             UPPER (class_name),
             1,
             CASE WHEN UPPER (class_name) LIKE 'MATH%' THEN 4 ELSE 3 END)
       || LPAD (
             ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY class_type ORDER BY class_type),
             4,
             '0')
          class_code
  FROM tbl_class
```

**EDIT:** I didn't realize that the `WITH` clause could cause misunderstanding, so i have deleted it.

Comment: It works, but I'd still have to manually add the statement for all the class_name and class_type.

Comment: There's duplication in the Class_Code and I'd have to add the select class_name, class_type manually since I have over a hundred of classes.

Comment: you realise that the `With tbl_class as ...` section is just Jon creating a subquery containing some sample data that is aliased as tbl_class, so that in the main sql statement (starting with `select class_name, substr(upper(class_name)....` can query data without having to create a separate tbl_class table, right? Since you already have a table called tbl_class with data in it, you can just use the main sql statement.

Comment: Thank you Boneist for making that remark. @Thade S: As your question is not entirely clear I showed what could be relevant for you. But you will have to fit it to your particular case. Good luck!